# How do I stop text expanding horizontally in RDLC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

The text long text inside RDLC column keeps expanding right horizontally and I can't stop it. I tried **CAN GROW to false** but nothing helped. How to control it, so the text keeps extending downwards in proper and good manner.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome... :) Anytime

Comment: put your answer in answer box so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you have entered as "Patwari Remarks" will be considered as a single word as there is no space in between....Ideally there is no such word in dictionary...so this case is incorrect...You should set `Can Grow` to true and try with proper and valid data..

Comment: Clearly your brilliance reflects that you are from IIT (Y)